# Can't able to create development certificate in developer portal of ios?

Tags: ios

I tried to create Development certificate in developer portal of IOS by
going to Certificates -> Development -> + button pressed. In the add screen "IOS App Development" radio button is disabled. And "App store and Ad hoc" radio button is also disabled

Following things i had tried but not working.

1. I had revoked two certificates and tried again still "IOS App Development" radio button is disabled.
2. Developer portal account is Admin account that permission had also checked

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 2):

You exceed the amount of maximum Development & Production certificates you can create. Revoke several certificates & try again. Then you'll be able create new

Comment: Among 8 developer certificates, i had revoked 4 certificates. Even after that Both "ios app development" and "App store and ad-hoc" radio button option is still disabled. What to do sir ?

Comment: Can't you revoke another 3 of them? because sometimes Apple gives you only 2 developer accounts to create if it's a personal Developer account

Comment: That 2 certificates were related to live apps sir.

Answer (score 0):

To submit your app to the app store you need to go to Development-> App Store and Ad Hoc. That is why revoking certificates isn't doing anything. Hope this helps.

Comment: App store and Ad Hoc option is also disabled. What to do ?