# How to recognize a touch event on UIImageView while animating in ios using objective c code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am animating 4 images in `UIImageView` by the following code. 
But the problem is image is not appearing in UIImageView. If i try removal of swipeImage code then image is appearing in UIImageView. How to make imageview appear in UIImageView ?

Oulet had made to UIImageView property, if i try to set image without animation code, UIImageView has image. Withanimation, UIImageView has no appearance of image. Thanks in advance for any help.

Property

```
@property (weak , nonatomic )IBOutlet UIImageView *imgslide;
```

Declaration

```
    int scrlNo;
NSTimer *aTimer;
```

View did load code

```
  scrlNo = 0;

    imgslide.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addGestures];
    [self SwipeImages];
```

Add gesture code

```
-(void)addGestures //Adding Single Tap Gesture here
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTap:)]; //init the TapGesture with the selector
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    [imgslide addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; //Add it to imgslide, not to self.view

}
```

ImageViewTap code

```
-(void)imageViewTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked image %d", scrlNo);
}
```

Swipe Images Code or animation code

```
- (void)SwipeImages
{
    if (scrlNo==1) {

        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_2.png"];


        scrlNo=2;
        [aTimer invalidate];

        aTimer = nil;
        aTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(SwipeImages)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];

    }else if (scrlNo==0) {



//        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_1.png"];
//        
//        [self.imageViewOutlet setImage:img];

        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_1.png"];


        scrlNo=1;
        [aTimer invalidate];

        aTimer = nil;
        aTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(SwipeImages)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];

    }
    else if (scrlNo==2) {

//        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_3.png"];
//        
//        [self.imageViewOutlet setImage:img];

        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_3.png"];


        scrlNo=3;
        [aTimer invalidate];

        aTimer = nil;
        aTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(SwipeImages)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];

    }
    else if (scrlNo==3) {


//        
//        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_7.png"];
//        
//        [self.imageViewOutlet setImage:img];

        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_7.png"];


        scrlNo=0;
        [aTimer invalidate];

        aTimer = nil;
        aTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(SwipeImages)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
    }
    else if (scrlNo==4) {

    }
}
```

Comment: probably easier to just make the UIImages into UIButtons that have the image as a background

Comment: But i want to animate images and to identify which image was clicked

Comment: I think you have to **disable** user interaction to force your `UIImageView` pass touch events to superview.

Comment: I had disabled "UserInteraction" in both storyboard and code but still touchesBegan code is not getting a call

Comment: this blog post should help http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/21228285860/hit-testing-animating-layers

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Interaction Enabled With CAAnimation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110485/user-interaction-enabled-with-caanimation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method & load this method on `viewDidLoad` instead of loading `SwipeImages` on `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)addTimer
{
    aTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(SwipeImages)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];
}
```

Then your viewDidLoad looks like

```
scrlNo = 0;

    imgslide.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addGestures];
    [self addTimer];
```

And Edit SwipeImages to this,

```
- (void)SwipeImages
{
    if (scrlNo==1) {
        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_2.png"];
        scrlNo=2;

    }else if (scrlNo==0) {
        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_1.png"];
        scrlNo=1;
    }
    else if (scrlNo==2) {
        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_3.png"];
        scrlNo=3;
    }
    else if (scrlNo==3) {
        imgslide.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promo_banner_7.png"];
        scrlNo=0;
    }
    else if (scrlNo==4) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it got worked. You saved my life today, seriously. Thank you so much sir. I updated some code in question sir.

Comment: Thanks you so much sir, problem is resolved. Can you please answer this question also ? Please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457310/cant-able-to-create-development-certificate-in-developer-portal-of-ios